# Why is Pip not working after upgrading Python to 3.8?

Tags: python, linux, pip, arcade

I was working on a 2D game using python 3.6.8 and pip3. Everything was working fine. Then i downloaded and installed python 3.8. Now, pip won't work at all. These are the errors I am getting when running "pip3 install arcade":

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting arcade
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/arcade/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/arcade/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/arcade/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/arcade/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/arcade/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/arcade/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/arcade/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement arcade (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for arcade
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

PLEASE HELP, I would like to continue making my game.

Comment: How did you install python? What OS are you running on?

Comment: @Jonno_FTW I installed python directly from the official website. I downloaded 3.8 then followed the readme instructions. I am on linux mint 19.2

Comment: You don't need to install python from the website on linux, you should be able to install it from your distributions repository. If you want a newer versions of python separate from the one that comes with the OS, use pyenv or conda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. You've got a broken `ssl` module, so you can't connect to HTTPS sites (like PyPI). Perhaps you installed the wrong build of Python, or it was built with a runtime dependency on a library (like OpenSSL) you don't have a compatible version of. Without further information, we have no way of knowing what caused the problem, only that your installation of Python 3.8 is broken.

If there isn't a Mint package for Python 3.8 yet, you can always [build it from source](https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-8-ubuntu/), but make sure to install all the dependencies first, or you'll just end up with another broken install.

Comment: THANK YOU ! I assumed it was broken after your comment, so I reinstalled from that source link and now pip is working correctly. Have a blessed night sir